# How to handle multiple login page display in jsp application when session timed out?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, session, tabs

I work on an jsp application where on main page we have left side menu and iframe to display content for the link selected. Only one link opens in a new tab and full page as it displays the details of application stacks and jobs running, much like a dashboard. We are using tomcat as servlet container. My problem is when session timed out from tomcat side login page is displayed but it gets displayed on both the tabs. My concern is, we want user to show only one login page for this we have use javascript code to know if the parent page is opened or not.

We have few scenarios :

1. If parent page is open, we close the child tab and open login page in parent windows. Works perfectly.
2. When parent window is closed, we open the login page in child window. Works fine.
3. However, if we open the dashboard in one tab and then click any link in the menu bar parent page is opened but is not linked to child window. When we use javascript code to know if the parent window is opened or not it comes as false. Now , child window open login page in child window and parent page also display login page.

How can I know if the parent window is still open and apply the logic to handle this scenario.